# componentWillReceiveProps not firing

Tags: reactjs

In my other classes, componentWillReceiveProps was working nicely, but for some reason, it isn't firing here.

ItemView.jsx

```
class ItemView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            name: null, 
            rating: null, 
            sector: null, 
            location: null, 
            description: null, 
            image: "blank.png",
            show: false
       };
    }

    ...

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        if(!nextProps.companyToRender) {
            this.setState({
                name: null, 
                rating: null, 
                sector: null, 
                location: null, 
                description: null, 
                image: "blank.png",
                show: false
            });
       }
       else {
           var companyToRender = nextProps.companyToRender;

           this.setState({
               name: companyToRender.name, 
               rating: companyToRender.rating, 
               sector: companyToRender.sector, 
               location: companyToRender.location, 
               description: companyToRender.description, 
               image: companyToRender.image,
               show: true
           });
    }

    ...

    render () {
       return(
        <div>
         ...
        <CommentBox show={this.state.show} companyToRender={this.state.name}/>
         ...
        </div>
       );

    }
}
```

CommentBox.jsx

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {companyToRender: null};
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({companyToRender: nextProps.companyToRender});
    }

    ...
}
```

The prop passed to itemView is either null if nothing is to be passed, or the array that ItemView is assigning to it.

componentWillReceiveProps() fires only when the state's attributes become null, but not when it sets. ( (null --> entry) doesn't work but (entry --> null) works).

Am I missing out on something? Thanks!

--
edit:

(null --> entry) updates state, but doesn't call the logs or any subsequent componentWillRecieveProps(). (But entry --> null does.)

[Logs for null --> entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcfId.png)

[Logs for entry --> null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L1DP.png)

Comment: Have you validated in `ItemView`'s `componentWillReceiveProps` or via chrome's `react` inspector plugin that the `name` state is being correctly set? It sounds like` ItemView` isn't re-rendering because `name` hasn't changed.

Comment: I tried logging the both inside the componentWillReceiveProps() function and in the render() function of CommentBox.jsx. Strangely, it doesn't print out the log inside componentWilRecieveProps(), but changes the state inside render() during null-->entry. I'll update the entry to show the output on chrome.

Comment: "The prop passed to itemView is either null if nothing is to be passed, or the array that ItemView is assigning to it."
Is it just a mistake in your question, or is ```companyToRender``` an array (as you say)? I guess it should be an object.
Also, be aware that componentWillReceiveProps is not called when the component is first mounted (but only after that).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After much painful debugging, I found out that the problem was that ItemView was being called inside a modal (react-bootstrap) which for some reason, doesn't support componentWillReceiveProps(). Ended up fixing the issue by refactoring the code. Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you find confirmation of this somewhere on the net or file a bug?

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Since the Modal has to create a brand new component every time there's changes, `componentWillReceiveProps` is never called (it's only supposed to be called when there's _new_ props, not initial ones).  Try putting your prop logic in the `constructor()` instead!  Also, ty for saving me a ton of time debugging.

Comment: Thanks for following up and posting what the issue was! I just experienced the same thing with a component inside a modal created with react-modal and your answer quickly alerted me to the issue.

Comment: Happened with me with a different library's modal and putting the code in constructor made it work. Thank you @JamesM.Lay

Answer (score 14):

If anyone else is having a problem with this...

`componentWillReceiveProps` will *not* be called if you are receiving the **exact same** props as before.  What you can do to get around it is add a dummy prop that iterates every time you want to send the same prop to the component in case that component internally resets itself somehow

```
click() {
    this.setState({counter: ++this.state.counter, unchangingProp:true})
}
<Component unchangingProp={this.state.unChangingProp} counter={this.state.counter}/>
```

This way `componentWillRecieveProps` will be triggered every time.

Comment: somehow updating the component state isn't triggering  `componentWillReceiveProps` either.

Comment: @JohhanSantana it is an intented behavior in the React Lifecycle, you can refer to [this picture](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/0*P5I1CUDhaZpytVhb.) to see what's happening.

Comment: I find this confusing and might lead users to wrong architectural choices and anti-patterns. I'd recommend reviewing the React docs considering patterns and anti-patterns. For example this page: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: This is a quick and dirty method. If you have a better solution please post and Ill upvote

Answer (score 6):

In my case my component was being re-created every render, so I had to put my logic in the constructor. I know its not ideal but it was a simple component and was easier for me to do than try to fix the issue that was causing the component to get re-created each time.

Comment: If you had to put your logic in the constructor, try use componentDidMount instead. It should be fired at the same time as the constructor is.

Answer (score 2):

i also had the same problem. if someone typed in a direct url the componentwillreceiveprops did not fire. i had to refactor my code as well to get it all working.

Changes i made was in my initial index.tsx having something like (i.e. have the router as the outer element):

```html
render( 
<Router history={hashHistory} >
{routes}
</Router>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

my default route was to my app.tsx page with a structure as follows:
 render() {

```
return (
 <Provider store={store}>
   <div id="appContainer">
           {this.props.children}
   </div>
 </Provider>
);
```

}