# Gatsby.js: Navigating with URL Parameters and the Browser Back / Forward Buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-router, back-button, browser-history, gatsby

I have an Articles component which displays a list of posts. The list is paginated so that a maximum of 10 posts can display per page. There is a "Next Page" button that when clicked will update the component state and the corresponding url parameter like so:

page 1: /news

page 2: /news?page=2

page 3: /news?page=3

...and so on. The way the `constructor()` and `render()` methods are set up, it will read this URL parameter and display the correct posts if the user navigates directly to /news?page=3, for instance.

The issue I'm having is that the browser back and forward buttons don't seem to rerender the page. So if a user hits the "Next Page" button a few times and then hits the back button, the URL will update, but the page won't rerender. Is there a way to force it to do so?

I'm guessing there's a way to accomplish this by adding a window.history listener, but I wasn't sure if there was a recommended practice to go along with `gatsby-link`.

Here is a stripped down version of the component for reference:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { navigateTo } from 'gatsby-link';
import getUrlParameter from '../functions/getUrlParameter';

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    /* external function, will grab value
    * of ?page= url parameter if it exists */
    const urlParamPage = getUrlParameter('page');
    const currentPage = urlParamPage ? urlParamPage : 1;

    this.state = {
      currentPage
    };
  }

  nextPage() {
    const { props, state } = this;

    const urlParam = state.currentPage > 1
      ? `?page=${state.currentPage}`
      : '';

    navigateTo(props.pathname + urlParam);
    this.setState({currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1});
  }

  render() {
    const { props, state } = this;

    const articles = props.articles
      .slice(state.currentPage * 10, state.currentPage * 10 + 10);

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {articles.map((article) => <li>{article.title}</li>)}
        </ul>

        <button onClick={() => this.nextPage()}>Next Page</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you check if `componentWillReceiveProps` is fired on back/forward button clicks ?

Comment: hm it is not being fired at all, on back/forward clicks or the initial component load

Comment: Which version of gatsby are you using? Also do you see any console errors when navigating via browser buttons?

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani I am on gatsby version 1.9.158 and no console errors are appearing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your page doesn't rerender because it is actually the same page - **the component is already mounted**. As you are fetching your data in `constructor()`, your page won't update because the constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)).

What you call `urlParam` are just a new prop that `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` should receive in `nextProps.location.search`.

#### Edit:

You have to lift state up because only the root component  will receive `props.location` on browser back and forward buttons. The `pathname` prop of your Articles component nerver changes, that is why `componentWillReceiveProps` never fires here.

#### The code:

#### /src/pages/root.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { navigateTo } from 'gatsby-link';

import Articles from '../components/Articles';

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentPage: 1,
      data: {}, // your ext data
    };

    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
  }

  nextPage() {
    const { currentPage } = this.state;
    const { pathname } = this.props.location;
    const url = `${pathname}?page=${currentPage + 1}`;

    this.setState({ currentPage: currentPage + 1 });
    navigateTo(url);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { pathname, search } = nextProps.location;
    const getParam = /(\d+)(?!.*\d)/;

    const currentPage = search !== '' ? Number(search.match(getParam)[0]) : 1;

    /* get your ext. data here */
    const data = {};

    this.setState({ currentPage, data });
  }

  render() {
    const { currentPage, data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {/* other contents here */}
        <Articles
          nextPage={this.nextPage}
          currentPage={currentPage}
          data={data}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### /src/components/Articles.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Articles = ({ nextPage, currentPage }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Page: {currentPage}</div>
      <button onClick={() => nextPage()}>Next Page</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Articles;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Nenu, however it seems that `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method is never called, on initial page load or when navigating with the Next Page button

Comment: This is strange. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325715/componentwillreceiveprops-not-firing) that sometimes componentWillReceiveProps doesn't fire for obscure reason... I encourage you to create a new page in your gatsby project and see if componentWillReceiveProps works (this is what I did before answering thid code example). Then try debugging this one or refactor your code structure.

Comment: I had the same intuition, sounds weird that it does not fire when your route change

Comment: Well within my gatsby project, a page imports and displays this component. My guess is that because it's not actually linking to a new page and instead updating the inner component's state and subsequently updating the URL, that is resulting in the back / forward buttons not having any effect. Is there a way I could make it load the whole page as if it were navigating from another?

Comment: Oh I see. Well I think I got it. According to your code, you are passing a `pathname` prop to this component, which should be equal to `props.location.pathname` right ? If so, it is normal that `componentWillReceiveProps` isn't firing in your Articles component as `pathname` never changes. I would recommend you to lift states up. I edited my answer in this way.

Comment: Hm I lifted the state but `componentWillReceiveProps` is still not firing for me when using the back / forward buttons. Is it working for you?

Comment: @dougmacklin Yes it works well for me with the code above. I think we lack of information about your issue then... I think it will be easier if you can provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to test your code.

Comment: @Nenu it turns out that in addition to lifting state, I also needed to update gatsby / gatsby-link! I was on versions 1.9.158 and 1.6.34 respectively and after updating to 1.9.231 and 1.6.39 it started working. thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

This can be resolved using history object present inside window object.

Another way is using the React-Router-DOM, which is the latest routing module for routing in ReactJS Applications. So for reference to V4 router follow this code.

```
  import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
```

After importing router, just try to scope your root Component inside it, then you can, create routes inside it.

```
  <Router>
    <div className="App" id="App">
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About}/>  
      <Route path="/misreports" exact component={MISReport}/>  
      <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact}/>  
    </div>
  </Router>
```

> keep in mind that router should contain only single child other wise, it won't work as expected. This way routing becomes very easy to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Amit, however I don't think the react router solution applies to this particular case. Could you maybe demonstrate the solution using the history object?